# I got an 'Access violation' error on a brand new untouched project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xna-4.0, access-violation

I have Visual Studio 2013 installed. I also have XNA 4.0 installed, but that's not causing the problem since I tried creating a project without using an XNA template or XNA code, and I got this same error. I'm running this on Windows 7 64 bit. I created a project called "Tetris Attack". I did absolutely nothing with the code, so it's just simply everything given in the template. What should happen is the code should run, and I should get a window whose contents are simply the color blue. I tried to run it in debug mode (the same thing happens in release mode), and I got this in the output window:

```
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'd:\temporary\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Tetris Attack\Tetris Attack\Tetris Attack\bin\x86\Debug\Tetris Attack.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris Attack.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tetris Attack.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[5916] Tetris Attack.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5916] Tetris Attack.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

It didn't run the program. I get the same problem no matter what project I try to run. It gives me some stuff not relevant to this problem in the output, then it gives me what I have above. How do I fix this? The code runs just fine if I "start without debugging", so there must not be anything wrong with the code.

Update: I tried installing Visual Studio 2013 on a separate computer and tried debugging various types of projects on that, and I have not experienced this problem in any way. It must have something to do with my computer. What does anyone think it is?

Comment: access violation? Can you show some code you wrote.?

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution to my problem. Make sure you are running Visual studio as an administrator. This is for Windows 7.

**To make Visual Studio always run as an administrator:**
-Right click the shortcut that leads to the Visual Studio exe.
-Click "Properties".
-Go to the "Compatibility" tab.
-Check the box "Run this program as an administrator".
-Click "OK".

**To run Visual Studio as an administrator once:**
-Right click the shortcut that leads to Visual Studio.
-Click "Run as administrator".